# Mistake in basic reshape function, wide to long format

Tags: r

I have the following wide format dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A.1 = c(0, 1, 0), A.2 = c(1, 
1, 0), B.1 = c(99, 99, 0), B.2 = c(99, 99, 0)), .Names = c("ID", 
"A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.2"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

   > df

  ID A.1 A.2 B.1 B.2
1  1   0   1  99  99
2  2   1   1  99  99
3  3   0   0   0   0
```

Now I am changing it to long format:

```
long.df<-reshape (df,idvar = "ID", varying=c(2:5),v.names= c("A", "B"), 
timevar="time",direction="long", sep = ".")
```

Here's the resulting long data frame:

```
 > long.df
     ID time  A  B
 1.1  1    1  0  1
 2.1  2    1  1  1
 3.1  3    1  0  0
 1.2  1    2 99 99
 2.2  2    2 99 99
 3.2  3    2  0  0
```

So, this conversion is not correct and the values became confused. For example, the value of parameter B for ID 1 for timepoint 1 changed from 99 to  1,   the value of parameter A became 99 for IDs 1 and 2 at second timepoint and so on.

The expected output should be as follows:

```
 > expected.long.df
     ID time A  B
 1.1  1    1 0 99
 2.1  2    1 1 99
 3.1  3    1 0  0
 1.2  1    2 1 99
 2.2  2    2 1 99
 3.2  3    2 0  0
```

Have no idea why it happened. Would be very greateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the `varying`.  We need to specify the patterns correctly

```
reshape(df, idvar = "ID", varying = list(grep("^A", names(df)),
      grep("^B", names(df))), direction = "long", v.names = c("A", "B"))
#    ID time A  B
#1.1  1    1 0 99
#2.1  2    1 1 99
#3.1  3    1 0  0
#1.2  1    2 1 99
#2.2  2    2 1 99
#3.2  3    2 0  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun, you've got the essence of the issue. I regained my confidence in using basic R functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `tidyr` library:

```
library(tidyr)
temp1 = gather(df, key = "x", value = "y", -ID)
temp2 = separate(temp1, x, into = c("z", "time"), sep = "[.]")
temp3 = spread(temp2, key = z, value = y)
```

The `temp3` table looks like your desired result, but not exactly the same order.  Use `dplyr`'s `arrange` to get it right:

```
> dplyr::arrange(temp3, time, ID)
  ID time A  B
1  1    1 0 99
2  2    1 1 99
3  3    1 0  0
4  1    2 1 99
5  2    2 1 99
6  3    2 0  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ameya and lebelinoz. Your answers a great and both work well with my data. Voted for Ameya solely as the data.table is more familiar to me and I more easily understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You're essentially looking at a `melt`ing operation.

```
library(data.table)
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A.1 = c(0, 1, 0), A.2 = c(1, 1, 0), B.1 = c(99, 99, 0), B.2 = c(99, 99, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.2"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
dt <- setDT(df)
melt(dt, id = 'ID', measure = patterns('^A.', '^B.'), value.name = c('A', 'B'), variable.name = 'time')
   ID time A  B
1:  1    1 0 99
2:  2    1 1 99
3:  3    1 0  0
4:  1    2 1 99
5:  2    2 1 99
6:  3    2 0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on you `reshape` and  `stringr`:`str_split_fixed`

```
df=melt(df,'ID')
df[,c('Time','Name')]=str_split_fixed(as.character(df$variable),"[.]",2)
df$variable=NULL
reshape(df, idvar = c("ID","Name"), timevar = "Time", direction = "wide")

  ID Name value.A value.B
1  1    1       0      99
2  2    1       1      99
3  3    1       0       0
4  1    2       1      99
5  2    2       1      99
6  3    2       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Wen